# How to stop HTML to insert data into database when wrong input taken

Tags: javascript, html

So I have my form here

```
<form name = "reservation" method = "post" action = "makereservation.php"  autocomplete="off">

(my codes here)

<input type = "submit" value = "Submit"  onclick="checkPhoneNumber(document.reservation.contact)">

</form>
```

And my Javascript function here to detect wrong length of phone number

```
    function checkPhoneNumber(contact)
    {
        var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;               

        if(contact.value.match(phoneno))  
        {  
            return true;  
        }  

        else  
        {  
            alert("Not a valid Phone Number");  
            return false;
        }
    }
```

What I want to ask is that how do I stop from inserting into database when the input for phone number is wrong?

What I got now is that it detects wrong length of phone number but it still insert into database.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<form name = "reservation" method = "post" action = "makereservation.php"  autocomplete="off"
onsubmit="return checkPhoneNumber(document.reservation.contact)">



<input type = "submit" value = "Submit" >
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast and precise solution.